# Is it possible to append code to the CakePHP-generated document.ready block?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I currently use the CakePHP JsHelper as follows and I would like to run additional JavaScript code when the document is ready:

```
    echo $this->Js->get(':submit')->event('click', "$(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(':submit').val(\"Saving...\");
        ",
             array('stop' => false));
```

The above code is in my default.ctp and is inserted into every single page in this website application. I would like to add the additional code inside 1 page. The code would  append a button with certain properties and events dangling from it. Is it possible to do so?

I have already tried having 2 documentReady functions (1 generated by CakePHP and the other inside a *.js file) to no avail.

Here are the current contents of the 2nd .js file:

```
//source: http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/cakephp-ajax-quick-save-jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
$('<input type="button" value="Insta-Save"/>')
.click(function(){ 
$(this).parents("form:first").ajaxSubmit({
success: function(responseText, responseCode) {
$('#ajax-save-message').hide().html(responseText).fadeIn();
setTimeout(function(){
$('#ajax-save-message').fadeOut();
}, 5000);
}
});
return false;
})
.appendTo('form div.submit');
});
```

I also tried using a code block but CakePHP insisted on stuffing the code in at the very top of the page and so naturally, IE complained.

Comment: You can add as many jQuery ready handlers as you want. It's an event stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success!

Simply append to the CakePHP buffer as follows:

```
echo $this->Js->buffer('alert("Hello world!");');
```

And, just as the commenter pointed out above, everything works just fine with the 2 resulting documentReady functions.